# aapt: Return code 139 after adding google-play-services_lib

Tags: android, eclipse, osx-mountain-lion

I have that error when i add google-play-services form eclipse on Proyect Preferences --> Android- >library using mac osx.
Sometimes when i could compile it give me the error:
Android Packaging Problem: resources.ap_ does not exist
If anyone knows the error please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Did you add the google Ad view somewhere in the code or this problem occurs only when you add the external `.jar` file?